# An internal error has occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":No address associated with hostname ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So weird about Android Firebase Authentication
This is my code

```kotlin
fun createAccount(email: String, password: String){
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener {
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.d("mAuth", "OnFailureListener $it")
            }
            .addOnCanceledListener {
                Log.d("mAuth", "OnCanceledListener")
            }
    }
```

Then it came to addOnFailureListener, and this is the log

```sh
2021-01-15 19:12:41.135 1073-1799/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.wellbeing.api
2021-01-15 19:12:42.122 8337-8337/com.example.gobishops D/mAuth: createUserWithEmail:failcom.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":No address associated with hostname ]
2021-01-15 19:12:42.122 8337-8337/com.example.gobishops D/mAuth: OnFailureListener com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com":No address associated with hostname ]
2021-01-15 19:12:52.304 216-698/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup34: Permission denied
2021-01-15 19:12:52.296 216-216/? W/Binder:216_4: type=1400 audit(0.0:138): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup34" dev="sysfs" ino=18820 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-01-15 19:12:52.308 216-698/? E/android.system.suspend@1.0-service: Error opening kernel wakelock stats for: wakeup35: Permission denied
2021-01-15 19:12:52.308 216-216/? W/Binder:216_4: type=1400 audit(0.0:139): avc: denied { read } for name="wakeup35" dev="sysfs" ino=18880 scontext=u:r:system_suspend:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:sysfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-01-15 19:12:57.201 1607-8386/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox W/GmsLocationProvider: Error removing location updates: 16
2021-01-15 19:13:00.003 736-736/com.android.systemui D/KeyguardClockSwitch: Updating clock: 1213
```

which indicates that I had some network issue when connecting to [www.googleapis.com](https://www.googleapis.com), that's true when I tried to open this URL in the browser, however, when I ping this address, everything looks fine, no package loss.

Comment: Got solved, there's some problem with the simulator in Android Studio. When I run this project on a real device, everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an issue with Firebase package you have installed. Try to reinstall the entire project in the emulator.

I would try running on a physical device first before doing anything just to be sure it's not an emulator issue.

If that still doesn't work then your best bet is to reconfigure the project with Firebase.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's a native Android project without flutter though. But that's absolutely the emulator error.

Comment: I had that same exact issue a while ago and the solution is to clean the project and wipe/cold boot emulator.